# Creating recursive rectangles in applet - AP Computer Science Recursion Lab17b

Tags: java, recursion, applet, awt, drawing

**This is the end goal:** [image: This is the end goal.]

The question asked me to make a recursion that fills rectangles like the image above, and I have been able to expand the rectangles to the up-left corner, but not the other corners. I need help as to how I could draw rectangles in other corners: I have tried methods like increasing the parameters (maxX and maxY) but they increase the rectangle size as well.

My program is:

```
// This is the 100 point version.
// Xingjian Wang
// 2020
// APCS, Chris Robinson

import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;


public class Testing02 extends Applet {

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        drawSquare1(g, 1000, 650, 6);
    }

    public void drawSquare1(Graphics g, int maxX, int maxY, int i) {
        int midX = maxX / 2;
        int midY = maxY / 2;
        int startWidth = maxX / 3;
        int startHeight = maxY / 3;
        int tlX = midX - (startWidth / 2);
        int tlY = midY - (startHeight / 2);
        if (i == 6) {
            g.fillRect(tlX, tlY, startWidth, startHeight);
            drawSquare1(g, maxX / 2, maxY / 2, i - 1);
        }
        else if (i == 0) {
            draw4(g, tlX, tlY, startWidth, startHeight);
        }
        else {
            draw4(g, tlX, tlY, startWidth, startHeight);
            drawSquare1(g, maxX / 2, maxY / 2, i - 1);
        }
    }
    public void draw4(Graphics g, int tlX, int tlY, int startWidth, int startHeight)
    {
        g.fillRect(tlX, tlY, startWidth, startHeight);
        g.fillRect(tlX, tlY + startHeight * 3, startWidth, startHeight);
        g.fillRect(tlX + startWidth * 3, tlY + startHeight * 3, startWidth, startHeight);
        g.fillRect(tlX + startWidth * 3, tlY, startWidth, startHeight);
    }
}
```

This is the outcome: [image: This is the outcome.]

Comment: What parameters are you using? Is it possible that you can create a runnable program that can be copy'n'pasted directly for us? Are you using JavaFX?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question and add in the parameters & runnable programs. Also, I'm not using JavaFX.

Comment: I tried to compile this in Java 11, and I get `warning: [deprecation] Applet in java.applet has been deprecated`. When I try to run it, I get `please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application`. What version of java are you using?